# moving DB from one host server to another with certificate and encrypted stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, encryption, certificate, database-backups

How to move sql database (sql server 2008 r2) from one host server to another if I do not have access to database server so I cannot use `Restore` from `*.bak` (it seems the only way to load data is using Generated script, but below are described problems I have)

a) db has Certificate and Symmetric Key
    CREATE CERTIFICATE PasswordFieldCertificate 
       ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MyPass'
       WITH SUBJECT = 'My DB Certificate'
    GO

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordFieldSymmetricKey WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordFieldCertificate;
GO
```

b) db has encryped Stored Procedure, with Decryption tools, I got the following code for it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Encryption_key] WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
Begin
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordFieldSymmetricKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordFieldCertificate with PASSWORD='MyPass';   
END
```

The only thing I imagine I can do: 
- restore backup locally
- generate script with `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements
- run script on newly created db
But I have the following problems:

a) this method doesn't provide anything regarding Certificates and Keys. Should I somehow create those by myself on new db? How to do this properly, so that I have exactly the same algorithm as it was before and all data could be encrypted/decrypted correctly as before on old server.

b) this doesn't allow to generate script for encrypted Stored Procedure, right? Should I run it by myself?

c) when INSERT scripts are generated (using `Task -> Generate Script`), the result contains very strange symbols that simple cannot be inserted. For example, one insert statement is something like this:

```
-- this code is generated but when run it shows Incorrect syntax
INSERT [dbo].[Person] (... [EmailAddress]) VALUES (N'紀눬묮䣹疋ⴐǸ)
```

I could not even copy/paste the full code it doesn't appear. But INSERT statements contain "hieroglyphs". And when running script it shows `Incorrect syntax near '紀눬묮䣹疋ⴐǸ'.`

P.S.
I have no knowledge about `certificates/keys`, this is the first time I have to deal with them. Previously I always used simply restore from `*.bak` file. Unfourtunately, now I cannot upload backup to new host server (at least I do not get how to do that, we are using GoDaddy as new host server).

Comment: is this sql-server or mysql???

Comment: This is sql-server (2008r2)